# type 'string' is not assignable to type ' long short narrow undefined'

Tags: typescript

I copied following code snippet from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString and tried it in my own project.

```
const event = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));
const options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
console.log(event.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', options));
```

However I get this error on my parameter 'options':

Argument of type '{ weekday: string; year: string; month: string; day: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DateTimeFormatOptions'.
Types of property 'weekday' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"long" | "short" | "narrow" | undefined'.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desired type of `weekday` is: `"long" | "short" | "narrow" | undefined`

As you can see, it is not a `string` type - it is a union of predefined constants (or undefined).

Meanwhile, your `options` is inferred to the following type:

```ts
{
    weekday: string;
    year: string;
    month: string;
    day: string;
}
```

You need to prevent widening your literals to string.

There are 3 ways to do that:

- `as const`assertion
- explicit type for `options` variable
- inlining the variable

```ts
// Option 1: as const assetion
const options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' } as const;
// inferred to:
// { 
// readonly weekday: "long";
// readonly year: "numeric";
// readonly month: "long";
// readonly day: "numeric";
//};
console.log(ee.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', options));

// Option 2: Explicit type
const options2:  Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
console.log(ee.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', options2));

// Option 3: inlining options
console.log(ee.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' }));
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=55&pln=7&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBApnGBeGY4HcYBECGU4AUu+AdAKoAqAwgQEwAMAjLQDQyONsNsDMb9-AJSCA3ACgxAekkwA8gAcoAS3DsAXDBwQYoSLC0Q4y8GN3QYIRSsjIYAbxjoEAawAmOAJ4aA5ABtwAObebB5wOABOPmAArgC2cOFKwMEwseBQABY+-mBBbO5eMN4x8YnJMAC+mtpmUOJmIL5wJP4BBAgkUCAAMiDAOE3EcADKUIm5BN6ucAC0WACiKZbGkMLiUjIKKzC0GvMAHvK+SUqwUB7ycKbg5svWELswMACSYFC+JEMUSvEAYiDhWJ4Lb3WwOJxwNyebKBFKhCJROIJJIpNJvLJFHJ5GAFRGlFGVeo3RrNVrtZpdXr9QZ4EZjJQTKazBZLKw3WhrCTSORssAwHgaBnHMAMgIWXkQa6QEktEBtDqUvoDOBDUbjNpMuaLNjgly4zGwkJhSJFErI5JsNGZGG5FL64pIsreSprIA)

Comment: Thanks, it removed the error on the options. However when I run this exact code in my project i get the output "12/20/12" instead of the expected "Donnerstag, 20. Dezember 2012". Any idea why?

Comment: You would need to give more info on how you setup and run your project. I got the correct output in both typescript playground and in my browser devtools